# Preventing URL encoding in links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with an MVC web app. My Home/Index page displays a table through a series of AJAX calls from dropdown lists and button presses. I currently have it set up to store what links are being chosen in `location.hash`. On loading the page it looks in `location.hash` and calls the appropriate functions to recreate the page as intended. I have links working like `http://localhost:xxxxx/Home/Index#1`.

My 2 questions:
A: On a separate page I am trying to link back to this page with `@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Home/Index#1")`. Unfortunately the URL gets encoded to `http://localhost:xxxxx/text/Home/Index%231` causing it to not work. How can I prevent this and get the proper URL to be passed?

B: I am trying to get my submit to link to a specific spot on my index page. `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`. Where and how would I add a link to get the submit to take me to `http://localhost:xxxxx/Home/Index#1` rather than `http://localhost:xxxxx/Home/Index`?

I know asking two questions isn't good, but I thought these were similar and related enough to be okay. Any information on either or both is appreciated.

Comment: You put the link you would like to navigate to on a successful form submit in the `action` attribute of the form tag. i.e: `<form method="POST" action="Home/Index#1">`

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Thank you. That is now getting it to link to the correct spot. Unfortunately, it has the same problem as the other link. It's going to `http://localhost:xxxxx/text/Home/Index%231` changing the `%23` to a # makes the link work.

Comment: hash makes no sense on a form action because hash never goes across the wire to the server. use an onsubmit handler or a GET param+history.pushState to avoid the reload.

Comment: I'm wanting the reload. My Home/Index page checks the hash and then calls the AJAX functions to update the page. This will allow the user to see the results of their changes from the submit. I'm just using the hash as a convenient place to store where the user needs to be/is in a page and the commands that AJAX uses to get the page there.

Answer (score 0):

A: The URL gets encoded automatically with HTML helpers that I found. I instead just used `<a href="~/Home/Index#1">Cancel</a>`. It's not quite as fancy, but works.

B: My problem was in my controller. I send my data back to the controller to handle and then transfer to index from there. I was using a RedirectToAction, but again it encodes.`return Redirect("~/Home/Index#1");` seems to be working.

If there are obvious problems with these solutions, please share. Otherwise at the moment, this seems to be the solution.